# Move, sent email to folder

Tags: email, outlook-2010, rule-engine

**Is there a way to move sent emails from the sent folder to another folder if it's sent to a certain address.** Outlook rule editor for Outlook-2010 only allows to Move AND Copy when choosing to apply rule to messages that have been sent. (while messages received allows for only moving.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SaveSentMessageFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868473(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class allows to set a Folder object that represents the folder in which a copy of the e-mail message will be saved after being sent. So, the message will be placed to the correct folder.

```
  Sub SetSentFolder() 
   Dim myItem As Outlook.MailITem  
   Dim myResponse As Outlook.MailITem 
   Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder 
   Dim mpf As Outlook.Folder 

   Set mpfInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
   Set mpf = mpfInbox.Folders.Add("SaveMyPersonalItems") 
   Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
   Set myResponse = myItem.Reply 
   myResponse.Display 
   myResponse.To = "Eugene Astafiev" 
   Set myResponse.SaveSentMessageFolder = mpf 
   myResponse.Send 
  End Sub
```